# Visual studio extension resource files

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have developed a visual studio extension and I have a custom button that I want to style using PNG images, but the image files/resource files wont show while in action and the button is blank.

[image]

I have a custom button template.

```
<Style x:Key="openFilebtn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid Name="bgGrid">
                            <Image Name="btn_bg"  Source="/vsPlayer;component/Resources/open.png"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="btn_bg" Value="/vsPlayer;component/Resources/open.png"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="btn_bg" Value="/vsPlayer;component/Resources/open_hover.png"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="btn_bg" Value="/vsPlayer;component/Resources/open.png"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="btn_bg" Value="/vsPlayer;component/Resources/open.png"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="btn_bg" Value="0.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Double and triple check that the path to the image is correct. Including this part: `/vsPlayer;`.

Comment: I have, it works in other project types, but whet it comes to extensions or custom toolbox controls resource files wont show up.

Comment: What do you have the build action property set to for that image?

Comment: build action property is set to none.

Comment: The problem was the build action property option, I've changed it to Resource and now it works fine. Thank you Chris W.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like I was saying, always make sure you have your build action property set correctly on assets like images you're including in the build. In your case, setting it to Resource does the trick.

Glad you got your remedy, cheers!